# Why is my pc Sound muffled in earphones but becomes okay when I press and hold the play button

Tags: windows-10, audio, dell-inspiron, headphones, realtek-hd-audio

The sound is muffled, the base sound are all cut out when I plug in headsets via the 3.5mm jack but when I press and hold the play button it sounds okay.

Headsets without a pause/play button work fine

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Realtek audio driver but nothing has changed

Comment: " play button" what play button exactly?

Comment: The button for play/pause on wired earphones

Comment: Does your headset also have a microphone?

Comment: Yes it has a microphone

Comment: I think your earphones are broken.

Comment: They work fine on other devices